# Degree Sequence Graph Theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

For each of the following degree sequences, either draw a graph with this degree sequence, or prove that no such graph exists.
$(i) (1,2,2,3,4,5) $
$(ii) (1,2,2,3,4,4) $
$(iii)  (1,2,2,3,5,5) $

$(i)$ - By handshaking lemma this isn't possible as a graph must have an even number of vertices with odd degree but it has $3$ vertices with odd degree and $3$ is odd and not even.

$(ii)$ See the image attached below. Is there an easier way of doing this though because it took me $5$ minutes to figure out. I think I overcomplicated it.

[image]

$(iii)$ Not possible. Let $V = ${${A,B,C,D,E,F}$}$ $ Imagine that $A$ and $B$ have degree $5$. This means that vertex $A$ must be adjacent to vertices $B,C,D,E,F$ and vertex $B$ must be adjacent to vertices $A,C,D,E,F$. This means the vertices $C,D,E,F$ are adjacent to $A$ and $B$, so they all have minimum degree of $2$. This means no vertex of the vertex set $V$ can have degree $1$, so the graph can't be drawn.

Can someone check my justification for $(iii)$ please ?

Comment: @kabenyuk thanks. so my justification I gave in my question is correct ?

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct.

Comment: @kabenyuk thanks. Are $(i)$ and $(ii)$ good as well. ?

Comment: Yes, this reasoning is also correct.